# Django query: all users with the given email

Tags: sql, django, simplify

Can this be written more elegantly in Django?

```
User.objects.filter(pk__in=EmailContact.objects.filter(email=email).values_list('user__pk', flat=True))
```

I want to fetch all users with the given email address through the `EmailContact` table.

`User` has a `emailcontact_set`, if that helps.

Thank you.

Comment: Soooo... `User.objects.filter(emailcontact_set__email=email)`?

Comment: Thx, Pavel @Gasanov, I felt I was being a тормоз. Why don't you make an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter related model `EmailContact` backwards by calling their RelatedManager `emailcontact_set`, like this:

```py
User.objects.filter(emailcontact_set__email=email)
```